# Spock executing actual rather than mock

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I have the following methods in a class call DeployArtifacts:

```
def call(List artifacts) {
    String methodName = "deployStream${artifactType.toString()}"

    for (artifact in artifacts) {
        "${methodName}"(artifact)
    }
}

def deployStreamSOA(Map artifactDetails) {
    String artifactName = getDownloadArtifactName(artifactDetails)
    String targetName = getDownloadArtifactTarget(artifactDetails)
    String modifiedConfigFileName = getUpdatedConfigFileName(artifactName)
    deployArtifact(artifactName, targetName, modifiedConfigFileName)
}
```

I am trying to check that deployStreamSOA is called with the following test:

```
def "type is SOA then deployStreamSOA is called"() {
    setup:
    def artifactList = [[groupId: "com.company", artifactId: "artifact1", version: "1.0.0"]]
    DeployArtifacts deployArtifacts = Spy(DeployArtifacts, constructorArgs: [ArtifactType.SOA]) {
        deployStreamSOA(_ as Map) >> ""
    }

    when:
    "DeployArtifact call is passed the SOA ArtifactType"
    deployArtifacts.call(artifactList)

    then:
    "the deployStreamSOA method is called"
    1 * deployArtifacts.deployStreamSOA(_)
}
```

But it is executing the actual deployStreamSOA method.

I thought that it may be to do with the dynamic method name generation, so I tried changing it to a normal method call, but still had the same response.

If I mock the methods inside deployStreamSOA method as well, then it passes, with it returning the mock values.

Why is it not mocking deployStreamSOA, but mocking the other methods?

How do I get this working without mocking all the internal methods this calls?

Comment: Would it be asking to much to request your sample code to be full classes, ideally an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? As an experienced SO user with 31k reputation you should know how to ask questions and make it easy for others to answer them.

Answer (score 2):

In order to fix your application code and make it actually call the expected method, please change

```groovy
"methodName"(artifact)
```

into

```groovy
"$methodName"(artifact)
```

---

**Update:** As for the actual explanation why your original method is called and not the stubbed spy method, the explanation can be found in the Spock manual, chapter [Combining Mocking and Stubbing](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing). It is a mistake many Spock newbies make and even some more experienced users might forget about it once in a while:

> Mocking and stubbing of the same method call has to happen in the same interaction.

I.e. you can fix your test like this:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q57108265

import spock.lang.Specification

class DeployArtifactsTest extends Specification {
  def "type is SOA then deployStreamSOA is called"() {
    setup:
    def artifactList = [[groupId: "com.company", artifactId: "artifact1", version: "1.0.0"]]
    DeployArtifacts deployArtifacts = Spy(constructorArgs: [ArtifactType.SOA])

    when:
    "DeployArtifact call is passed the SOA ArtifactType"
    deployArtifacts.call(artifactList)

    then:
    "the deployStreamSOA method is called"
    1 * deployArtifacts.deployStreamSOA(_) >> ""
  }
}
```

Comment: a) won't make a difference I don't think, as it _is_ a list

Comment: Of course, Tim. I updated my answer. Thanks for your feedback. The first part must have been a leftover from my thoughts about what could be wrong with the code, but it was actually okay. The culprit really was the OP's oversight in his application code.

Comment: I updated the answer one more time, providing the solution to OP's actual question. Sorry, I was in a hurry and totally forgot about that. I am not that sloppy usually. Shame on me!

Comment: Haha, happens to everyone 

Comment: Thanks.  As someone who is used to JUnit and completely new to Spock, I was not aware of this and missed it in the documentation.  Of course, you are correct that I should have provided a fully working example.  I will try better next time